# Using only the ratio test....

Tags: limits, summation

Using only the ratio test, determine whether or not the series: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k\Longrightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{5^k}$$ converges, diverges, or yields no conclusion.

Comment: What is $a_k$? Could you explain the sign $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: Filling in values in an equation you can use a $Longrightarrow$

Comment: That's a really strange notation...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k\Longrightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{5^k}$$

---

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=$$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{k+1}{5^{k+1}}}{\frac{k}{5^k}}\right|=$$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{k+1}{k}\cdot\frac{5^k}{5^{k+1}}\right|=$$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\left|\frac{k+1}{k}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{5^k}{5^{k+1}}\right|\right)=$$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{k+1}{k}\right|\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{5^k}{5^{k+1}}\right|=$$
$$\left|\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k+1}{k}\right|\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{5^k}{5^{k+1}}\right|=$$
$$\left|\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{k}}{1}\right|\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{5^k}{5^{k+1}}\right|=$$
$$\left|\frac{1+0}{1}\right|\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{5^k}{5^{k+1}}\right|=$$
$$\left|1\right|\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{5^k}{5^{k+1}}\right|=$$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{5^k}{5^{k+1}}\right|=$$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{5^k}{5\cdot5^k}\right|=$$
$$\left|\frac{1}{5}\right|=\frac{1}{5}$$

Since the limit equals $\frac{1}{5}$, the ratio test tells us that the series converges.